# Calculating progressive monthly averages

Tags: microsoft-excel

This might end up being super simple, but I can't seem to put my finger on it. What I'm attempting to do is having a 'rolling' average for the month. So, if we are on week 2 of the month, it will average those 2 weeks, and not the entire month with the missing data. I'm currently just using the average() formula as a default, and I was thinking it would do what I wanted, but when I check the raw data, it's not calculating correctly. I feel I missing something very simple. My main workaround is to pull the raw data every week and have another section for the monthly summary, but I don't have to have to pull the data twice each week.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Excel AVERAGE tool ignores truly blank cells already. If your predictive cells are being included in the average, they are not truly blank, and you may need to use a different tool.

AVERAGEIF= allows you to specify a single value to be excluded from an average operation. AVERAGEIFS= allows you to specify multiple values that will be excluded.

Here is a good discussion of more ways to solve this problem: http://excelribbon.tips.net/T007729_An_Average_that_Excludes_Zero_Values.html

Comment: This is awesome thank you for the reply. What I'm doing is averaging vlookups for each week, and one or more weeks will have no values. When that happens, I want to have the average for the weeks that do have values.